# List of users in chat room

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently working on a webpage. The Webpage is like a chat network, so I have multiple chat rooms that users can open and chat with other people.

My problem is that I don't really know the best way to show the users that have entered a chat room. Do I use a session variable to store the users that are in a chat room or something else? 
I'm thinking I shouldn't store this in a database since it updates and changed all the time.

I'm using MVC 3 for this application.

Thanks in advance, and please ask if something is unclear.

Comment: This depends on so many things. What are you using to make/manage to chat rooms? Are you using a framework for this, or did you roll your own solution? If the former, they may provide some method for this. If the latter, the implementation will limit possible answers to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a session variable because that is unique per session.  One way off the top of my head would be to create a ChatUser class that has all the information about the user in it, then create a Cache object for each channel on the server that has a List generic collection in it.

As users join the channel, they are added to the cached List and as they leave a channel, they are removed from the cache List collection.

This will keep everything in memory.